# Update label in custom UITableView Cell

Tags: swift, button, label, cell

I need to Update an label by clicking on an Button in the same cell. Why does my code doesn't work ?

```
@IBAction func actionFaveUnfave(sender: AnyObject) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(sender.indexPath)
    println(cell?.labelFavedTimes)

   cell.labelFavedTimes = "22"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cell?.labelFavedTimes.text = "22"`

BTW
`self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(sender.indexPath)`
can return nil if cell is not visible

Comment: The cell is visible, with the question mark xcode now says (I think the problem is my custom cell?): UITableViewCell' does not have a member named 'labelFavedTimes

Comment: Did you connect your UILabel in xib with property in your cell class using Interface Builder?
Also, try `var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(sender.indexPath) as! youCellClassName`

Comment: Yes...but in an external swift file for the cell class TableViewCellHome: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelFavedTimes: UILabel!
}

Comment: Try `var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(sender.indexPath) as! TableViewCellHome`

Comment: Whene I use `var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(sender.indexPath) as! youCellClassName` Xcode recognizes the  `cell.labelFavedTimes.text = "22" ` but says Error: nil while emulation

Comment: As I said cellForRowAtIndexPath can return nil if indexPath is out of bounds or corresponding cell is not visible

Comment: I just checked the value  of `sender.indexPath`....it's nil so is there anything missing in the IBAction?

Comment: If you user only 1 section I recommend setting `tag` property of button in cellForRowAtIndexPath
`cell.button.tag = indexPath.row`
And then in @IBAction:
`let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using superview...here is my solution:

```
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let view = button.superview!
    let cell = view.superview as! TableViewCellHome

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    println(indexPath)
    if(indexPath != nil){
        var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! TableViewCellHome
        cell.labelFavedTimes.text = favedTimesInt +  " Faves"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.labelFavedTimes.text = "22"
```

Comment: Yes i missed that by coping the code :D But the problem is that he didn't get the member "text" from labelFavedTimes (labelFavedTimes is also no Xcode suggestion of cell)

Comment: you must change your cell as your custom cell:                                           let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(sender.indexPath) as! customCell